# How to select pages option in PrinterDialogBox

Tags: tcl, printers

I tried to select the pages option in printer dialog box .

I have used the following command.

```
Printer dialog select flags [expr 0x0000002] .
```

But it is not enabling the pages option in printer dialog box.

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: What environment are you in? Which software package provides the `Print` command?

Comment: Printer Package provides the Print command.Please refer this link:[http://www.schwartzcomputer.com/tcl-tk/print/prntproc.tcl.txt]